# ASP.NET Validator Scripts Missing

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, validation

For some reason, on some of my pages, the default validator script isn't rendering with the page.  The reason makes sense; I'm using the Telerik RadAjaxPanel, which scenario-wise I could just also say UpdatePanel.  The panel wraps the pages and AJAXifies the responses.  Initially, the controls do not have a validator on the page, and thus, the validation scripts are missing.

Regardless of the reason, is there a way to render the Validation script manually with the  ScriptManager?  Is this embedded in the System.Web DLL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a hidden control/validator in the master page, and then this issue went away.  HTH someone.